# Wireless Connection problem (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a peculiar issue with my wi-fi connection. The title says that it's 21.04, but it happened on 20.04, so I think it's some sort of local issue, which I cannot pinpoint.

I have another machine that runs Ubuntu 20.04, a Windows machine and several Android phones that can successfully connect and get internet access, however this particular machine can only connect, but does not have internet access and can't even reach the default gateway.

Please help me pinpoint the issue, because everything seems to be in order, based on what I've read on other threads and as I tried to troubleshoot, but I don't understand all these low level details, and obviously the issue is local.

Result of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
```

Result of `lshw -C network` (I will show only the relevant Wireless part)

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 40:49:0f:a6:c4:6f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.191 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:b4000000-b41fffff
```

Result `iwconfig`

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Tenda"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E8:65:D4:87:04:01   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:76   Missed beacon:0
```

Please help, before I pull the trigger and start a fresh install :D

Comment: Try `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` then reboot, it might work with power management disabled

Comment: @Jeremy31 it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Try `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off`

Comment: Didn't work either unfortunately @Jeremy31